# Order By Matched Column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that is an audit log of changes to an account. Each account has a lot of different columns related to it. I then have a second table that contains an audit of the changes made to the account table's entries. This table looks like this:

[image: Table Example]

I have the current value of the order, but I do not have the original value of the order, and there are no timestamps of when the changes were made, so to find out the original value, I need to put the order audit information in order by linking the 'NEW_VALUE' column to the 'OLD_VALUE' column, and put them in order by which ones match up until we can work back to which entry in the audit table is the first one, which will tell us what the original value is. How would I write a SQL query that puts this audit table in the order they were done by matching the old and new values of different rows?

So in the example above, assuming I know what the newest value is, how would write a query that orders the values by matching them up, working backwards from the value I know is the current one?

Comment: Are the old vs. new values all distinct? What should happen if multiple rows appear to match another?

Comment: The old and new columns are not distinct, but the order ID is distinct.

Comment: If they’re not distinct then what you are trying is not possible. If the value for an order/line can be repeated (I.e. can be 1111 more than once) then you have no way of determining which one to join to

Comment: You say `Order_ID` is distinct, but your table shows all rows have a value of `1`.

Comment: _"So in the example above, assuming I know what the newest value is, how would write a query that orders the values by matching them up, working backwards from the value I know is the current one?"_ - even with non-distinct values, you can still use a recursive CTE (but make sure you add a depth-limiter) to show possible matches for each row.

Comment: With the caveat that @NickW mentions, you can do this using a procedural UDTF provided that the number of rows in the partitions formed by ORDER_ID and LINE_NUM are small - a few thousand rows per partition max.

Comment: Sorry, ORDER_ID is not distinct in the audit table, only the base table.